# Stored procedure delete query

Tags: database, stored-procedures, sql-delete

I have stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[k_ShoppingCart_DELETE]

@cartGUID nvarchar

AS

DELETE FROM
  [dbo].[k_ShoppingCart]
WHERE
  CartGUID = @cartGUID
```

When I execute this,

```
exec dbo.k_ShoppingCart_DELETE '32390b5b-a35a-4e32-8393-67d5629192f0'
```

Result: 0 row (s) affected.

But, when I try this query:

```
Delete FROM k_ShoppingCart Where CartGUID = '32390b5b-a35a-4e32-8393-67d5629192f0'
```

Result: 2 rows affected.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: you don't seem to have specified a size for @cartGUID. I believe you need to specify a size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist on using NVARCHAR instead of UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, you need to specify the size:

```
@cartGUID nvarchar(36)
```

Without it, your guids are being truncated ([to 30 characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276823.aspx)).

You can confirm this behavior by running this modified version of your working query:

```
DECLARE @cart nvarchar, @sizedcart nvarchar(36)
SET @cart      = '32390b5b-a35a-4e32-8393-67d5629192f0'
SET @sizedcart = '32390b5b-a35a-4e32-8393-67d5629192f0'

-- works
Delete FROM k_ShoppingCart Where CartGUID = '32390b5b-a35a-4e32-8393-67d5629192f0'

-- will not work
Delete FROM k_ShoppingCart Where CartGUID = @cart

-- should work
Delete FROM k_ShoppingCart Where CartGUID = @sizedcart
```

I agree with @Marc Gravell, though, uniqueidentifier is the way to go here.

Answer (score 3):

Should `@cartGUID` be a `uniqueidentifier` rather than an `nvarchar`? It is more efficient to cast a single varchar to a guid and compare the guids than it is to cast all the guids to varchar, and hope that it uses the same format (else equality will fail anyway).

As others have pointed out, the `WHERE` clause looks funky, but my money is on the varchar conversion being the culprit.

Comment: I agree, try changing the @cartGUID to uniqueidentifier, and also the column CartGUID should be of type uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored proc SQL seems a bit strange, did you copy it properly?

This doesn't look like it will compile to be honest:

```
WHERE
  CartGUID =@cartGUID

in (Select
```

Answer (score 0):

What's with that IN statement at the end of your stored proc?  It doesn't make any sense.  Just get rid of it.  Also, prefix all of your tables with "dbo" in the query and in the sproc (who knows, you might have another version of the same table in your default schema).  Doing those two things should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose you have the same table under multiple schemas...

```
dbo.k_ShoppingCart

vs.

user1.k_ShoppingCart
```

The stored procedure is using "dbo" while the ad-hoc query is using the current user reference.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing that looks strange to me: If cartID is a GUID (and a unique identifier) why does your delete statement affect two rows?

Also, try adding a length to the definition of cartID, maybe some funky default length definition leads to the input parameter being shortened or filled with blanks or something.

Comment: Maybe shoppingcart has a row for each item in a customer's cart.

Comment: Could be, but then I'd expect a table name like cart_items or so .. guess you've nailed the answer, though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

Solution: 
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[k_ShoppingCart_DELETE]

@cartGUID nvarchar **(50)**

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should update your question with these followup notes. This isn't a discussion board--use the comments or question for question-related info, and answers for answers. I'm glad you figured it out. This particular issue has bitten me before.

Comment: You should also accept the "best" answer .. (giving you and the person that helped you some more reputation).

Comment: I really think you should consider going with Marc--his answer is the right way to do this.